# Access text from a UITextField in another class

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uitextfield

I want to pull the user input text from a `UITextField` in a separate class so I can save it to my parse database. When I try to save the database appears empty for the name string.

I am pulling the text from this view controller

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
var newName = String()

@IBAction func DropLocation(sender: AnyObject){
    SaveName().setporta()
}
```

And I want to save it using this class

```
class SaveName: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate{

var user = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
var ad = PFObject(className:"Post")
var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
var name = String()


func setporta() {
    name = ProfileViewController().name!.text!

    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user!)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() {(uobject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            self.ad["name"] = self.name ?? NSNull()
            self.ad.saveInBackground()
        } else if let uobject = uobject{
            uobject["name"] = self.name ?? NSNull()
            uobject.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice on how to make it save using the SaveName class?

Comment: How are you transitioning from ProfileViewController to SaveName??

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I fixed it. It's correct in the Xcode project

Comment: I'm calling that class with a button. I updated the ProfileViewController to show that.

Comment: I'm surprised that `ProfileViewController().name!` doesn't crash.  You're creating a new object without loading its outlets.

Comment: I also suggest you look into MVC structure, which would lead you to the idea of moving data management out of your view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe I am terrible at asking questions but my solution was this.

```
var newName = String()
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!


@IBAction func DropLocation(sender: AnyObject){
newName = name.text!
SaveName().setporta()
}
```

Then my DropLoc class looked like this

```
class SaveName: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate{

var user = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
var ad = PFObject(className:"Post")
var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")


func setporta() {
name = ProfileViewController().name!.text!

query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user!)
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() {(uobject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        self.ad["name"] = name ?? NSNull()
        self.ad.saveInBackground()
    } else if let uobject = uobject{
        uobject["name"] = name ?? NSNull()
        uobject.saveInBackground()
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for all the responses hope this helps anyone else stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should slightly change your method lke this:

```
func setporta(nameFromtextField:String) {
    name = nameFromtextField
//rest of the code
.
.
.
}
```

And then call your method like this :

```
SaveName().setporta(name!.text!)
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that in `SaveName` you're not using the actual `ProfileViewController`. You're creating a **new instance** of `ProfileViewController` instead.

This is where you go wrong;

```
Name = ProfileViewController().name!.text!
```

`ProfileViewController()` creates a new instance, which has a new `name` UITextField, which of course is empty, because it's new.

Instead, and assuming both your original `ProfileViewController` and `SaveName` are in the same `UINavigationController`, you can try to access the original UITextField by looking in the `viewControllers` property.

For example (pseudocode and unchecked, don't copy paste this);

```
func setporta() {
    // At what index is the current view controller?
    let currentIndex = self.navigationController.viewControllers.indexOf(self)

    // Get the original ProfileViewController
    let profile = self.navigationController.viewControllers[currentIndex]

    // Get the text from the filled in UITextField
    name = profile.name!.text!

... snipped ...

}
```

However, **this is bad form** and hard to maintain, since ViewControllers should know as little as possible about each other. Instead, when you push the `SaveName` onto the screen, you should pass the `ProfileViewController`'s textfield entry first. Not access it later.

Comment: I basically agree with you but, since he's also doing `SaveName().setporta()` (more object initialization), it gets even stranger.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
the fact that you write :
Name = ProfileViewController().name!.text!

actually create a ProfileViewController and try to get the name, which is an empty string, because you are not presenting the screen and the user can't therefore type in it.

So what you want to do is:
 - present the ProfileViewController
 - have the user type their name in it, in the textfield
 - upon the press of an ok button or anything else, get the text from the profile view controller.

Present the ProfileViewController

you can use, from your SaveName class (unfortunate naming, ViewController's subclasses name should end with ViewController) :

[self presentViewController:[[ProfileViewController alloc ]init]
                 animated:YES
                 completion:nil];

2- Have the user type their name in the textfield

Well not much to do here.

3- get the name back

Best way of doing so would be by using the delegate patterns, but, in swift, you might as well add a closure to the view controller so it knows what to do when the ok/cancel button is clicked, and set it before presenting the view controller.

result would be roughly :

```
    class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

        var completionHandler:((name:String)->Void)?

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!

    // var newName = String() // useless...

    // Call this when user is done typing is name...
    func onOKButtonClicked() -> Void
    {
        if let c = completionHandler
        {
            c(name:name.text!);
        }
    }

}

class SaveName: UIViewController{

    /* ... */

    func presentProfileViewController() -> Void
    {
        let pvc = ProfileViewController();
        pvc.completionHandler = { name in

            self.recordName(name);

        }
        self.presentViewController(pvc, animated:true, completion: nil);
    }

    func recordName(name: String) -> Void
    {
        // send name to parse...
    }
}
```